# How to check stability of high entropy alloys

Tags: alloys, special-quasirandom-structures, alloy-theoretic-automated-toolkit, publishing

I have designed a high entropy alloy using mcsqs code. Now I want to check its stability. I am wondering if someone can suggest to me what are the minimum parameters that must be reported in a research paper to claim that the designed HEA can be synthesized in the laboratory.

Comment: you cant ever claim it can be synthesized, only that its thermodynamically on the hull...which i suspect is hard to define here.  You may not get a good answer on this.